# C# assignment, Binary file types

Tags: c#

I am a starting student in C# and I can't find the answer for the following question:

"*Write a program to open a text file and save the individual high and low 4 bit nibbles of each byte and in a binary file. Write a program to do the reerse, i.e reads two bytes from a binary file, combines them and writes them as a text file.*"

I can read code, and understand it. But since i'm new to this field, it's hard for me to actually come up on it completely on my own.

I've already wrote the code to open a .txt file and to save it as an .txt file.

Image of form1: *Since I lack the "reputation" I can't post images. :(*

And this is the code I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace _9._3_menustripAndFiledialog
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument docToPrint =
        new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Clear rich text box
            richTextBox1.Clear();

            //Set open file dialog initial directory and title
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\"; //Hier zeg je welke directory drive hij moet openen
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Please select a file";
            openFileDialog1.Filter= "Text files(*.TXT)|*.txt";
            MessageBox.Show("Only .txt files can be opened.");

            //Open the dialog and check for cancel
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                // niet gecanceled - lees bestand
                richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Gosh darn it! You pressed cancel!");
            }
        }

        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                // niet gecanceld - schrijf het bestand
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            } else {
                MessageBox.Show("You pressed cancel!");
            }
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Display a message box asking users if they
            // want to exit the application.
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "My Application",
                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                  == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AboutBox1 frmAbout = new AboutBox1();
            frmAbout.Show();
        }

        private void cutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Cut();
        }

        private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Paste();
        }

        private void undoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Undo();
        }

        private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Copy();
        }

        private void redoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Redo();
        }

        private void findTextToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Find("Text", RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
            richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Italic);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
        }

        public void replaceTextToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("Text", "newText");
        }

        private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            printDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
            printDialog1.ShowHelp = true;

            printDialog1.Document = docToPrint;
            DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                docToPrint.Print();
            }
        }
```

//Code starting from here are added from user: Xanatos

```
        public static void ReadSplitWrite(string inputFile, string outputFile)
        {
            using (var sr = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
            using (var sw = File.Create(outputFile))
            {
                int read;
                byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[4096];
                byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[inputBuffer.Length * 2];

                while ((read = sr.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < read; i++, j += 2)
                    {
                        outputBuffer[j] = (byte)(inputBuffer[i] & 0x0F);
                        outputBuffer[j + 1] = (byte)(inputBuffer[i] & 0xF0);
                    }

                    sw.Write(outputBuffer, 0, read * 2);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ReadMergeWrite(string inputFile, string outputFile)
        {
            using (var sr = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
            using (var sw = File.Create(outputFile))
            {
                int read;
                byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[4096 * 2];
                byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[inputBuffer.Length / 2];

                while ((read = sr.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < read; i += 2, j++)
                    {
                        outputBuffer[j] = inputBuffer[i];
                        outputBuffer[j] |= inputBuffer[i + 1];
                    }

                    sw.Write(outputBuffer, 0, read / 2);
                }
            }
        }
```

//I made a custom button to support the read and write method and to have it inside my form

```
        private void openAndSaveAsBinaryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadSplitWrite("inputfile.txt", "output.dat");
            ReadMergeWrite("output.dat", "inputfile2.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some help on this matter! :)

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: The question is not complete, some important words are missing. The binary output will contain bytes. Each nibble in a separate Byte? As least significant Nibbles?

Comment: so you have done all that isn't the assignment and want to know how to do the assignment? Because in the assignment I don't see anything about a user interface (and when I did assignments like these, I usually created command line tools to do them)

Comment: It doesn't help to show us liners like: `MessageBox.Show("STAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHPPPPPPPP!");` Please remove this **LOUD NOISE**

Comment: @HenkHolterman: 1. I wanted to show you folks how my form looked like to give an Idea. 2. Oke, I understand. But how do I realise that? :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried something and this is what I came up with as sollution to the question.

```
private void openAndSaveAsBinaryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string dirPath = @"C:\";

        //read from folder: C:\
        //create directory if it doesn't exist

        if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
        }

        string fileName = @dirPath + "/TestFile.bin";

        //Create binary file if it doesn't exist
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            //File doesn't exist - create file
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
            BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            byte[] byteArray = { 0x48, 0x45, 0x4C, 0x4C, 0x4F }; //HELLO!

            for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
            {
                bw.Write(byteArray[i]);
            }

            bw.Close();
            fs.Close();

        }

        // reads back

        FileStream fsRead = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fsRead);

        for (int i = 0; i < fsRead.Length; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(br.ReadByte().ToString());
        }

        br.Close();
        fsRead.Close();
    }
```

What it does: It creates a new directory if it doesn't exists. Also, it writes the .bin file now and returns it to me in a MessageBox as Binary. (Converted .ToString()). After that it saved it in the directory,and it converts it in the .bin to readable text.

I think this is what the assignment asked from me.

**I want to thank you folks for the help, without it I couldn't have done it :)**

Comment: Where are the nibbles in your solution?

Comment: @Henk: I had no clue what nibbles actually were. Because you asked this question I looked it up, and I don't have it. Well, hmm. Have to do research a bit more. Thank you for making me aware!

Answer (score -1):

Here there are two methods, the first one splits, the second one merges. Note that your assignment isn't clear if you have to shift the second nibble after splitting it or not... To make it clear:

```
0xFF
```

should I split it to:

```
0x0F 0xF0
```

or to

```
0x0F 0x0F
```

I choose the first one.

```
public static void ReadSplitWrite(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    using (var sr = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
    using (var sw = File.Create(outputFile))
    {
        int read;
        byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[4096];
        byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[inputBuffer.Length * 2];

        while ((read = sr.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < read; i++, j += 2)
            {
                outputBuffer[j] = (byte)(inputBuffer[i] & 0x0F);
                outputBuffer[j + 1] = (byte)(inputBuffer[i] & 0xF0);
            }

            sw.Write(outputBuffer, 0, read * 2);
        }
    }
}

public static void ReadMergeWrite(string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
    using (var sr = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
    using (var sw = File.Create(outputFile))
    {
        int read;
        byte[] inputBuffer = new byte[4096 * 2];
        byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[inputBuffer.Length / 2];

        while ((read = sr.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < read; i += 2, j++)
            {
                outputBuffer[j] = inputBuffer[i];
                outputBuffer[j] |= inputBuffer[i + 1];
            }

            sw.Write(outputBuffer, 0, read / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
ReadSplitWrite("inputfile.txt", "output.dat");
ReadMergeWrite("output.dat", "inputfile2.txt");
```

If you look at the example, you will see that I read the file at blocks of 4096/8192 bytes at a time (`inputBuffer`), and then I have a second buffer where I put the splitted/merged bytes that I then write.

Comment: At first it wouldn't recognize File. so I added using System.IO; at the top of my Form1. I made a button regarding the ReadSplitWrite and tells me it doesn't find the "inputfile.txt". Do I have to manually create the file? PS: I will edit the current code with your code, to make it more clear.

Comment: @Skynzor You have to replace the strings with your filenames

Comment: I've added inputfile.txt to my obj/debug folder with in it 'test'. Now when I use the button I created for it it indeed makes inputfile2.txt and output.dat. Now comes my second question, what is the purpose by doing this? :) I thank you sincerely for helping me out on this matter. I can't vote you up because I lack the reputation points :(

Comment: Also, how do I start reversing this method? Since what it does now is: having a .txt file and duplicate it (backup) and create a .dat file (changed it to .bin). But now it needs to read things in the .dat (.bin now) and put it in the text editor. Could I maybe with the option 'openToolStripMenuItem_Click;' open .bin files too, and read it. Instead of seeing random ASCII. Going to try it right now.

Comment: I added the opening from (*.BIN) but now it shows as random ASCII code. It doesn't read the file. It used to say 'test' in my .txt file.